# How to sort json data first with numeric,second capital letters with alphabetic sort and then third alphabetically?

Tags: json, node.js, sorting

I have a json data like this

```
[ { groupType: '1',
    id: '158',
    unreadMessages: '8',
    ownerId: '332',
    name: 'porras group' },
  { groupType: '1',
    id: '163',
    unreadMessages: '0',
    ownerId: '337',
    name: '11..' },
  { groupType: '1',
    id: '173',
    unreadMessages: '0',
    ownerId: '334',
    name: 'cate\'s' },
  { groupType: '1',
    id: '174',
    unreadMessages: '0',
    ownerId: '328',
    name: 'raju' },
  { groupType: '1',
    id: '175',
    unreadMessages: '0',
    ownerId: '332',
    name: 'abcde' },
  { groupType: '1',
    id: '177',
    unreadMessages: '0',
    ownerId: '337',
    name: '26 feb' },
  { groupType: '1',
    id: '181',
    unreadMessages: '0',
    ownerId: '332',
    name: 'new' },
  { groupType: '1',
    id: '182',
    unreadMessages: '0',
    ownerId: '337',
    name: 'jchhabra group' },
  { groupType: '1',
    id: '186',
    unreadMessages: '0',
    ownerId: '337',
    name: 'jch' },
  { groupType: '1',
    id: '189',
    unreadMessages: '0',
    ownerId: '332',
    name: 'hebe' },
  { groupType: '1',
    id: '191',
    unreadMessages: '0',
    ownerId: '328',
    name: 'ccgg' },
  { groupType: '1',
    id: '202',
    unreadMessages: '0',
    ownerId: '332',
    name: 'New Porras Group' },
  { groupType: '1',
    id: '205',
    unreadMessages: '0',
    ownerId: '339',
    name: 'simgroup' },
  { groupType: '1',
    id: '210',
    unreadMessages: '0',
    ownerId: '339',
    name: 'check' },
  { groupType: '1',
    id: '222',
    unreadMessages: '1',
    ownerId: '333',
    name: 'jgonzalez group' },
  { groupType: '1',
    id: '223',
    unreadMessages: '0',
    ownerId: '334',
    name: 'Cate 2' },
  { groupType: '2',
    id: '150',
    unreadMessages: '0',
    ownerId: '0',
    name: 'BACKSTAFF Group 2' },
  { groupType: '2',
    id: '158',
    unreadMessages: '0',
    ownerId: '0',
    name: 'BACKSTAFF Group' },
  { groupType: '2',
    id: '173',
    unreadMessages: '0',
    ownerId: '0',
    name: 'BACKSTAFF Group 3' } ]
```

and i want to sort like

- 11..
- 26 feb
- BACKSTAFF Group
- BACKSTAFF Group 2
- BACKSTAFF Group 3
- Cate 2
- New Porras Group
- abcde
- cate's

> so on is that possible in json list to sort like 
>   numeric first then capital letters with alphabetic and rest
>   alphabetically.

Comment: is this question related to any specific programming language? If not ask in http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: this is in node.js

Comment: Do you want to reorder properties or object in collection? If the properties are the problem, I think you will need to change the properties order in the class, then reserialize. If the objects in the collection are what you want to sort, you can deserialize, and use .OrderBy() anr reserialize

Comment: i want to reorder the collection data like groupname "11" be the first in the json list is that possible?

Comment: It is possible in JavaScript. You can use your custom function to sort the array. Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you pretend to order it directly in code (and not in the data source like a database) you can write some simple code to do it.

First let's start with the basic compare function

```
function compareString(a, b) {
  if ( !(a && b) ) return Math.sign(a.length - b.length);

  const ca = a.codePointAt(0);
  const cb = b.codePointAt(0);
  const cmp = Math.sign(ca - cb);

  return cmp ? cmp : compareString(a.slice(1), b.slice(1));
}
```

After building the basic sorting function you can sort any object. Take your array of objects as an example:

```
const groups = //your groups here;
const sorted = groups.sort( (a, b) => compareString(a.name, b.name));
```

I'm using some ES6 syntax, let me know if you have any questions.

EDIT: I'm now on a car (not driving), I will explain the full code later.

EDIT2: Got this order using the code above (only with group names)

```
[ '11..',
  '26 feb',
  'BACKSTAFF Group',
  'BACKSTAFF Group 2',
  'BACKSTAFF Group 3',
  'Cate 2',
  'New Porras Group',
  'abcde',
  'cate\'s',
  'ccgg',
  'check',
  'hebe',
  'jch',
  'jchhabra group',
  'jgonzalez group',
  'new',
  'porras group',
  'raju',
  'simgroup' ]
```

EDIT3: While parking the car I've got an epiphany and realized that what you want is really the default string ordering of javascript. I was so focused on your problem and I forgot completely what I was doing. Anyway, I will let the code above as a reference. But you can use this code to sort your array

```
const sorted = groups.sort( (a, b) => a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1 )
```

How simple can it be? Basically it uses the same strategy of the code above, just compares the ASCII codes of the strings. Take a look at the [table](http://www.asciitable.com) to check the sorting priority of the function.

Things may get nasty with UTF8 surrogate pairs though

Comment: Although it requires more code, I would use the first approach, it is more future-proof. Right now you might not have to support anything more than ASCII but in the future you might. If you want to localize your code for other languages, many non-English languages (especially Asian ones) make heavy use of surrogate pairs. For more info about code-points and Unicode I would recommend [this talk](https://youtu.be/zi0w7J7MCrk).  

Comment: Hmm... actually since you used `slice` in your recursion that breaks when you hit a surrogate pair: `console.log(''.slice(1));`. You could maybe use a RegExp with the `u` flag to simulate a slice: `console.log(/.(.*)/u.exec('')[1]);` (that would require Node 6.0 or higher for `u` flag support) or perhaps rewrite it to use a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop instead of recursion.

Comment: The RegExp option would probably be pretty slow, not a good thing for a sort function, especially if the amount of data being sorted is significant. Another option would be to use the spread operator to turn it into an array and then slice the array instead of the string: `console.log([...''].slice(1).join(''));`. Performance testing would probably need to be done, I suspect this would be slow too but probably faster than RegExp. A `for...of` rewrite would probably be the best way of doing it.

Comment: You could also write a helper function that checks the first character to see if is equal to the first code-point and conditionally slice: `var tail = (s) => {
  var offset = s.charCodeAt(0) === s.codePointAt(0) ? 1 : 2;
  return s.slice(offset);
};` Then call it instead of `slice`: `return cmp ? cmp : compareString(tail(a), tail(b));`. That would probably be fast and not require refactoring the recursive code.

Comment: Interesting comments. When I wrote the code I was just traveling and I could really focus on what I was doing. But I really appreciate your input, just for fun I will do some testes of my own to see how it works when it comes to sorting emoji characters. It's always a learning experience

Comment: Yeah, ever since I watched Mathias' talk I've been in the habit of including 'Pile of Poo' tests in my unit tests, it helps spot oversights like that. He also wrote this great article: [JavaScript has a Unicode problem](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode). Another interesting article by SO co-founder Jole Spolsky: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).